# How to color a treeview node in javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

i have a treeview and a texbox that allows a user to search for nodes inside the treeview.

i already wrote the JS function that determines if a node exists in the treeview.
 what i want is to color the node that the user have searched for. how can i do this??

Comment: The question should be refrased to state a proper context. What kind of treeview? What part of the node do you need to change the color of?

I'm removing the c# tag as it has no clear connection to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Use CSS and change the className in Javascript.  So say your nodes are divs.  When you find the node, in Javascript, you would do something like:

```
divFoundNode.className = "selected";
```

Then make sure your CSS has a selected class with a background color set.  That would look something like this:

```
.selected {background-color:red;} /* whatever your selected color is here */
```

If you don't want to use CSS, you can change the color of the node directly by doing something like this:

```
divFoundNode.style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

Now, you'll probably also need to turn off the selection of whatever other node was previously selected first.  To do that, you've got a couple of options.  You can run through all nodes and remove the color before setting the selected one (like above) or you can store a variable in your Javascript with the last selected div and just target that one.  So you'd do something like this:

```
var divLastFoundNode; //global variable

function treeView_SelectNode(divFoundNode)
{
     divLastFoundNode.className = "";
     divFoundNode.className = "selected";
     divLastFoundNode = divFoundNode;
}
```

JQuery would make this quite a bit easier.  You can select lots of nodes and perform operations on all of them at once.  For instance:

```
$("div.node").removeClass("selected");
$(divFoundNode).addClass("selected");
```

Comment: Don't forget to reset all the nodes to a "neutral" className each time you do this, so you get rid of the old selects that no longer apply on subsequent searches.

Comment: I was just adding that as you commented. :)

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without some code, but how about this?

`document.getElementById("foundnodeid").style.color="#abcdef";`

Even though I'd rather change the class than the color directly, but that's up to you:

`document.getElementById("foundnodeid").style.class="classwithdifferentcolor";`